# How to show the users details automatically on Activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, database, facebook-login

I have app where user will login using facebook and fill the registration page. If later user wants to update the details, he can go to another activity Userupdate. So, my question is how can I show the details automatically in userupdate activity which he already filled in registration form like name, DOB or mobile number??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a requirements specification, not a question.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I am trying to pass user info from one to another activity..

Comment: If so, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Answer (score 1):

You can use

**1)Shared preferences** to store your user details,you can retrieve it and show

2)**SQLITE database** for android to store the details,you can retrieve it and show

Comment: bro can you please help me with codes?? or any article? it will be really helpful. thank you!

Comment: [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)      [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)  try this links... Understand how to use them

Answer (score 0):

you most save user details. u can use below links for how to save.

1: SqliteDatabase: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

2: SharedPreferences: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: I already saved.. just want to show it on another activity in edittext..how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** When `user` first fill registration page, then store user informations into local `sqlite` datebase or your online `server` database.

**2.** If `user` wants to `update` information, start `UserupdateActivity` and in `onResume()` method get the user information `data` from `database` and finally update the `view`.

Hope this will help to understand.

Comment: yes, the user info is saved in our db. however, i need codes to get the data from db and show it in userupdateactivity in edittext. please help me with the codes..

Comment: did you wrote any method to get user info from database?